# ReactJS Failed to compile: 'Objects' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

Can someone help me what is missing on my code? I'm trying to do this for a couple hours and error after error....

The objective is to fetch all objects coordinates into GoogleMaps Markers...

(Newbie at reactJS)

```
class maps extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = { Objects: [] }
    }

render(){

   {this.state.Objects.location.coordinates.map((item, i) => (
     <Marker position= {{ lat: Objects[i].location.coodinates[0], lng: Objects[i].location.coordinates[1] }}/>
    ))} 

    const MyMapComponent = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap((props) =>

    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={2}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.6333333, lng: -8.65 }} 
    >

    </GoogleMap>
  ))

    return(
        <div>
        <MyMapComponent
        isMarkerShown
        googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCnQmNcHpzoytzm02Zf-inD6xxTdSRJdLg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
        </div>
    )
}

componentDidMount(){

                axios.get('https://api.ost.pt/traffic_events/?key=VMSBvXtmOixXVuaHqeyAxDEhQkbnJpXZBYjDufEu').then( response => {

                    const { Objects } = response.data
                    console.log(Objects)
                    this.setState({Objects}) 

                })      
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error); 
                });

            }
```

}

[These are the objects.coordinates from api data that I need to fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lfIX.png)

Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Initially, `Objects` is an empty array. It is not fair to assume that this will have the property `location` in it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you're a complete newbie at react, why are you trying to build this instead of, say, some version of 'hello world'?

Comment: The data is still loading from axios when the component does its first render iirc, so you need to add a check to check to see if `Objects` is full of data before you try to access it, like `if (Objects.length)` is normally sufficent.

Comment: @brandNew open this pls. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lfIX.png. I want to achieve into all object location and coordinates to create markers on map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
{this.state.Objects.location.coordinates.map((item, i) => (
    <Marker position= {{ lat: Objects[i].location.coodinates[0], lng: Objects[i].location.coordinates[1] }}/>
))}
```

because you are mapping over this.state.Objects.location.coordinates, and you are using the index to access **Objects[i].location.coodinates[0]** and **Objects[i].location.coordinates[1]**, and **Objects** isn't defined anywhere, but this.state.Objects is.

I'm guessing you meant something like this:

```
 {this.state.Objects.map((item, i) => (
        <Marker position= {{ lat: item.location.coodinates[0], lng: item.location.coordinates[1] }}/>
    ))}
```

Here's an example of how to list the Lat/Long for each Object: http://jsfiddle.net/g4hr5jnc/

You just replace it with the Google maps components

Comment: it also prints an error: TypeError: item.location.coodinates is undefined

Comment: wait you can not put that code inside "render", like that it should be inside return, and put your MyMapComponent outside of render. The loop was just one of the issues.

Comment: I just updated my answer with  a JSFiddle so you can at least see the Lat/Long, you have to update the div contents with the google maps component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the code run `constructor(props)` first, then `render()` then `componentDidMount()`. Thus, when you run `render()` the `this.state.Objects` is still an empty array.
You may wanna try:
1. write whatever in `componentDidMount()` in to `constructor(props)`
2. change `componentDidMount()` to `componentWillMount()`

more about react component lifecycle:
http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/